# dar variable a instancia y hacer uso de una variable de otra clase

Tags: java

edit/
Mi fallo, quería que fuera lo mas simple de explicar y entender, pero termino resultando contraproducente, mis disculpas y muchas gracias por sus consejos señor benito.

bueno mi situación actual son dos problemas, el primero es que deseo crear múltiples instancias de la clase saltamontes esto acorde al tiempo que estipula la variable tiempo_reproducción,pero deseo que al momento de crear el nombre de dicha instancia tenga un numero que vaya cambiando, por ejemplo "saltamontes saltamonte1 = new saltamontes... y que dicho 1 se vaya cambiando por un 2, 3,etc, el problema es que dicho numero quiero que me lo de una variable, por eso tengo variables como hola y cadena, ya que estaba haciendo pruebas, pero no me funcionaba.

mi segundo problema que va relacionado con este es que deseo ocupar el método getcant_saltamontes como la variable numérica en la clase Reproducción, y la única forma es darle static a la variable cant_saltamontes , pero esto modifica hasta el et y set y no se si es la forma mas idónea, espero haberme explicado bien, cualquier sugerencia, ayuda o algo que este haciendo mal se agradece.

```
package proyectoprogra;

import java.util.Random;


public class Reproduccion {

private int min_reproduccion; 
private int max_reproduccion;
protected int tiempo_reproduccion;
protected int reloj_reproduccion;
protected int segundos;
public int hola = 5;
public String cadena;
public  void reproduccion(){
    cadena = Integer.toString(hola);
    
    Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    tiempo_reproduccion = rand.nextInt(max_reproduccion-min_reproduccion)+min_reproduccion;

    for(segundos = 0; segundos<tiempo_reproduccion;segundos++){
    delaysegundo();
   
    }
    if(segundos == tiempo_reproduccion){
        Saltamontes saltamonte = new Saltamontes("juan");
        saltamonte.getNombre();
        
    
    }

}  

private static void delaysegundo(){
    
    try{
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }catch(InterruptedException e){}

}
```

}

Dejo adjunta la clase Saltamontes en caso de que sirva para entender.

```
package proyectoprogra;


public class Saltamontes {


private String nombre;
private int cant_saltamontes;

//CONSTRUCTOR

public Saltamontes(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}


//GETTERS y SETTERS


public int getCant_saltamontes() {
    return cant_saltamontes;
}

//GETTERS AND SETTERS
public void setCant_saltamontes(int cant_saltamontes) {
    this.cant_saltamontes = cant_saltamontes;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
```

}

Comment: Bienvenido a SO, aquí no se hacen los deberes de nadie. Si quieres hacer una pregunta te recomiendo leer [ask] y hacer el [tour] para evitar que tu pregunta acabe cerrada o votada negativamente. Es importante que antes de hacer la pregunta ***investigues e intentes algo***, aunque no te salga. Si no vemos que te has esforzado y pones algo de código y un error concreto, no podemos aportar una respuesta, solo hacer las cosas por tí, y así ni tú aprendes ni nadie más se beneficiaría de tu pregunta excepto tú.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

con respecto a la segunda duda:

si, necesitas una variable estática iniciada a 0 o 1.
Podes crear un getter sin mayores problemas y crear un setter también pero, cualquiera de las instancias puede modificar el valor de la variable estática( es necesario??).

```
public class Saltamontes {

private String nombre;
private static int cantidad = 0;

public Saltamontes(String nombre) {
    // aumeto la cantidad cada vez que crea una instancia
    cantidad++;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    System.out.print("  "); // opcional ja
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public static int getCantidad() {
    return cantidad;
}

public static void setCantidad(int cantidad) {
    Saltamontes.cantidad = cantidad;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return nombre;
}
```

}

Prueba en main

```
ArrayList<Saltamontes> s = new ArrayList<>();
    
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) {
        s.add(new Saltamontes("juan "+(i+1)));
    }
    
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Existen "+Saltamontes.getCantidad()+" ");
    

    for(Saltamontes ss : s) {
        System.out.println("hola soy "+ss);
    }
```

**se pueden crear getter y setter de instancia removiendo el static o creando otros con distinto nombre*

Con respecto a la primera parte de la pregunta no me queda claro que querés hacer pero,  crear nombres de variables (o variables nuevas) en tiempo de ejecución, no es recomendado (* no se si es posible en java, alguien que me corrija si me equivoco*), utilizá una estructura de datos que permita almacenar una cantidad variable de instancias como un **arrayList** u otra mas conveniente para tu aplicación.